# Database treeview

Tags: java, php, sql, ajax, treeview

I've tried to make a simple treeview from a tutorial, on the internet.

[Guide with code I used](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html)

[Database from tutorial img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwIEg.png)

This works as it should

[php website of treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMy0C.png)

Now I want to make something similar with my own database, but it's not build the same way, though I do have the link between `TestSuiteCollectionName`, `TS_name` and `TC_name`, and their ids.

Now this is how my table looks (part of it)

[SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wucCU.png)

and the SQL code is

```sql
SELECT 
    testsuitecollection.id AS id,
    testsuitecollection.TestSuiteCollectionName,
    TestSuite,
    testsuite.TestSuiteName AS TS_name,
    testsuitetestcaselink.TestCaseId AS TC_id,
    testcase.TestCaseName AS TC_name
FROM
    testreportingdebug.testsuitecollectionlink
INNER JOIN
    testreportingdebug.testsuitecollection ON testsuitecollectionlink.TestSuiteCollection = testsuitecollection.id
INNER JOIN
    testreportingdebug.testsuite ON testsuitecollectionlink.TestSuite = testsuite.id
INNER JOIN
    testreportingdebug.testsuitetestcaselink ON testsuitecollectionlink.TestSuite = testsuitetestcaselink.TestSuiteId
INNER JOIN
    testreportingdebug.testcase ON testsuitetestcaselink.TestCaseId = testcase.id
ORDER BY id;
```

The view you can see should look like this

[Treeview structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXJlw.png)

I tried to change the tutorial code, so it works with my database, but I can't seem to get it to work, so maybe I don't filter the sql data right.

This is the code I use from the tutorial which works for me, with their database structure, not mine.

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM $db.country_state_city;";
    
    $result      = $MysqliHandler->query($query);
    //$output = array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
      $sub_data["id"] = $value["id"];
      $sub_data["name"] = $value["name"];
      $sub_data["text"] = $value["name"];
      $sub_data["parent_id"] = $value["parent_id"];
      $data[] = $sub_data;
    }
    foreach($data as $key => &$value)
    {
      $output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
    }
    foreach($data as $key => &$value)
    {
      if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
      {
        $output[$value["parent_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
      }
    }
    foreach($data as $key => &$value)
    {
      if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
      {
        unset($data[$key]);
      }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: _"I get alot of errors"_ - And those are? _"This is the code I use from the tutorial which works for me."_ - So your code works now? Is this basically just a blog post?

Comment: My database is not build the same way as in the tutorial as you can see, but I want to use my database and make a treeview out of it. and the code I used from the tutorial with their database NOT mine works, as it should because it's a tutorial.. My question is just how I can change the code from the tutorial, so it works with my database structure.

Comment: Did you actually understand the whole concept of id and parent_id to identify which row belongs to which row and the order? Your Table is absolutely nothing like it and does not have that relationship between rows... So how are you expecting it to work? This is like trying to put a square peg in a round hole. You need a round peg.